# How to execute a command after network startup on Solaris?

Tags: solaris

I need to execute a command after a network interface came up. On Debian I would use the `post-up` option in `/etc/network/interfaces`. But I can not find anything similar for Solaris 10. Is it possible to execute a command after network initialization?

Answer (score 3):

Solaris uses SMF to control the system and init(1m) just starts `/lib/svc/bin/svc.startd` that is controlled by xml files.

To learn how the system works, I recommend to read the man pages for `smf` (the overview), `svcs` (the service status reporter - run this first to understand more) and `svcadm` (the program to manage the system).

If you like to add a service that is run after the network is up, you should write a service description (xml) file that says "I depend on `svc:/milestone/network:default`" and install that service.

In order to be able to do more, you definitely would need to read the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Solaris takes its queue from I think unix 7, the `rc` scripts ie `run command` scripts, as does `*BSD` oses.

Have a look at the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19683-01/806-4073/6jd67r96g/index.html).

So under `/etc/rc*.d` are the scripts that executed during different run levels. `rc2.d` is the run level where networking is brought as shown by `/etc/rc2` script on Solaris 11, as I don't have Solaris 10 laying around

Comment: The file `/etc/rc2.d/README` states that the rc scripts are legacy initialization scripts. Instead I should prefer smf.

Comment: Your link describes Solaris 9.

Comment: I no little of solaris, I understand `rc` and how to use it as I use bsd, smf is a world away for me. Regardless if the docs are for solaris 9, the run levels will never change...any time soon

Comment: Correct, rc scripts still work but do not permit to let things depend on another action. This is why SMF has been introduced in August 2004.

Comment: Adding your script to /etc/rc3.d/S99<file> and hard linking it to /etc/init.d/<file> is the easiest.  If you want it to run right after the network is up and usable, use SMF as schily notes.